# Image not centered vertically in scrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

What am I missing? The inner scrollview and the image view fill the entire screen. But somehow my image is not centered. The top left corner of the image starts in the center of the view, but I would like to have the image nicely centered. Also during zooming.

```
-(void)prepareScrollView
{
    for(int i =0;i<[self.layoverPhotoAssets count];i++){
        PHAsset *asset = self.layoverPhotoAssets[i];

        FMImageZoomViewController *zoomController = [[FMImageZoomViewController alloc] init];
//        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        int x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        zoomController.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
        //zoomController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:zoomController.view];
        zoomController.zoomScroller.delegate = self;
        zoomController.imageView.tag = 1;
        [self.zoomControllers addObject:zoomController];

        PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat; //I only want the highest possible quality
        options.synchronous = NO;
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:zoomController.zoomScroller.frame.size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(result){
                zoomController.imageView.image = result;
                zoomController.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
        });
        }];

        //self.scrollView.contentSize= ;
    }
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [self.layoverPhotoAssets count], 0)];
    [self scrollToAsset:self.selectedAsset];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
    zoomController.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:zoomController.view];
```

That cannot be right. If `zoomController.view` is to be a subview of `self.scrollView`, its frame within `self.scrollView` is in terms of the *bounds* of `self.scrollView`, not the *frame* of `self.scrollView`.

Comment: That is true thanks...however no effect since both scroll views take the whole screen..the image is still too big or not centered

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
-(void)prepareScrollView
{
    for(int i =0;i<[self.layoverPhotoAssets count];i++){
        PHAsset *asset = self.layoverPhotoAssets[i];

        FMImageZoomViewController *zoomController = [[FMImageZoomViewController alloc] init];
//        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        int x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        zoomController.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
        //zoomController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:zoomController.view];
        zoomController.zoomScroller.delegate = self;
        [self.zoomControllers addObject:zoomController];

        PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat; //I only want the highest possible quality
        options.synchronous = NO;
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:zoomController.zoomScroller.bounds.size   contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(result){
                zoomController.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:result];
                zoomController.imageView.frame = zoomController.zoomScroller.bounds;
                [zoomController.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                zoomController.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                [zoomController.imageView setCenter: self.scrollView.center];
                zoomController.imageView.tag = 1;
                [zoomController.zoomScroller addSubview:zoomController.imageView];

//                zoomController.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
//                if (zoomController.imageView.bounds.size.width > result.size.width && zoomController.imageView.bounds.size.height > result.size.height) {
//                       zoomController.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//                }
            }
        });
        }];

        //self.scrollView.contentSize= ;
    }
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [self.layoverPhotoAssets count], 0)];
    [self scrollToAsset:self.selectedAsset];
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but it seems to me that the way you solved it is by doing what my answer said to do.